# Average and Sum Step by Step XSLT/XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tags

Here is a piece of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  ?>             
<output>                
  <cars>                
   <car>                
    <id>1</id>              
    <brand>Ferrari</brand>              
    <type>F12</type>                
    <license>B-1</license>              
   </car>               
   <car>                
    <id>2</id>              
    <brand>Volkwagen</brand>                
    <type>Golf</type>               
    <license>B-3</license>              
   </car>               
  </cars>               
  <distances>               
   <distance>               
    <id_car>1</id_car>              
    <date>20110901</date>               
    <distance>111</distance>                
   </distance>              
   <distance>               
    <id_car>1</id_car>              
    <date>20110902</date>               
    <distance>23</distance>             
   </distance>              
   <distance>               
    <id_car>1</id_car>              
    <date>20110903</date>               
    <distance>0</distance>              
   </distance>              
   <distance>               
    <id_car>2</id_car>              
    <date>20110901</date>               
    <distance>92</distance>             
   </distance>              
   <distance>               
    <id_car>2</id_car>              
    <date>20110902</date>               
    <distance>87</distance>             
   </distance>              
   <distance>               
    <id_car>2</id_car>              
    <date>20110903</date>               
    <distance>132</distance>                
  </distance>               
 </distances>               
</output>
```

Here is a piece of the xsl file I'm working on it:
(is there a way to put the id_car/id in a generic way? Because how it's now I must manually put a value for each id/id_car that I have in my xml file do attend my plans.)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                   
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"                    
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:template match="/">

  <html>                    
  <body>                    
  <h1>Cars</h1>             
   ID: <xsl:value-of select="output/cars/car/id"/><br />
   TOTAL KM: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/output/distances/distance[id_car='1']/distance)"/><br />
   KM/DAY: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/output/distances/distance[id_car='1']/distance) div count(/output/distances/distance[id_car='1']/date)"/> 


 </body>                    
 </html>                    
 </xsl:template>


 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the ID as a variable and call it on each one of your predicates then you dynamically update that predicate each time the code cycles through. For example, using for-each:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Cars</h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="output/cars/car">
                    <xsl:variable name="id" select="id"/>
                    ID: <xsl:value-of select="$id"/><br/>
                    TOTAL KM: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/output/distances/distance[id_car=$id]/distance)"/><br/>
                    KM/DAY: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/output/distances/distance[id_car=$id]/distance) div count(/output/distances/distance[id_car=$id]/date)"/> <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply-template is also a valid way to do this, but the use of the variable is the important part for this.

Comment: Jason H that works perfectly, can you, please, explain how and why these resolved my problem? I really wanna try to understand how it works,

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? It's hard to explain why this example works without giving you a 50-page tutorial on the key concepts of XSLT and XPath. Perhaps you need to do more background reading?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 has a built-in **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** mechanism that was designed specifically to handle situations like this, where cross references between two sections of the XML need to be resolved. Using it will make your code both more elegant and more efficient.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="dist" match="distance" use="id_car" />

<xsl:template match="/output">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Cars</h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="cars/car">
                <xsl:variable name="distances" select="key('dist', id)" />
                <xsl:variable name="total" select="sum($distances/distance)" />
                ID: <xsl:value-of select="id"/><br/>
                TOTAL KM: <xsl:value-of select="$total"/><br/>
                KM/DAY: <xsl:value-of select="$total div count($distances)"/> <hr/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

You can read more about XSLT keys here: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Comment: Michael.hor257k that is working perfectly as well! Thank you! But how do I know which distance tag iis that one that is in yout key declaration?